# Django rest framework router urls are empty

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build simple API with Django REST Framework running on Python 3.4.3. However, drf router urls turns out to be empty:

**Project tree:**

```
.
├── api
│   ├── profile
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── urls.py
└── config
    ├── settings
    └── urls.py
```

**Response from server:** *(it doesn't contain link to the viewset!)*

```
GET /api/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
{}
```

**./config/urls.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from app_profile.views import ProfileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include("api.urls", namespace='api')),
]
```

**./api/urls.py:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from api.profile.views import ProfileViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.conf.urls import include, url

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', ProfileViewSet, 'user')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**./api/profile/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from app_profile.models import Profile

from .serializers import ProfileSerializer


class ProfileViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

**./api/profile/serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app_profile.models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

I encounter the same problem with different models. I also tried to check what does router variable contain:

```
>>> print(router.urls)
[<RegexURLPattern api-root ^$>, <RegexURLPattern api-root ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>]
>>> print(router.registry)
[('users', <class 'api.profile.views.ProfileViewSet'>, 'user')]
>>>
```

And this is pretty mind-boggling. Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're inheriting from ViewSet - you need to specifically define the methods in the class

For your question , it would be better to import from ModelViewSet

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/